# Android development adding custom string to useragent

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to add a custom HTTP header to the webView of my android application to validate if the webView is running from our app.

When we use the webView.getSettings it shows an error message all the time.

```
Android.WebKit.Webview does not contain a defenition for getSettings()
```

This is our code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Views;

namespace LoadWebPage {
[Activity(Label = "LoadWebPage", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity {
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);
        webView.SetWebViewClient (new WebViewClient ());
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

        webView.LoadUrl("http://www.google.nl");


        webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;
        webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);    
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);


        };

    }

}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution fixed our problem.

```
string standard_agent = webView.Settings.UserAgentString;
webView.Settings.UserAgentString = standard_agent + "NEWUSERAGENT";
```